# Polymer 1.0 , Google Chart type="table" not working

Tags: polymer, google-visualization, polymer-1.0

In the given [Plunk example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OKTc4EM37sepvCotrvWk?p=preview), [Google "pie" chart](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-chart/elements/google-chart) is working

BUT "table" chart is not working(meaning, "table" chart is in the DOM but it is not visible AND also makes 'pie' to disappear).

Both examples are taken from the [demo docs](https://elements.polymer-project.org/bower_components/google-chart/demo/index.html) where both are working i.e. both are visible.

Why 'table' chart is not visible in the Plunk example?

```
<google-chart
    type="pie"
    data='[["ID", "Life Expectancy", "Fertility Rate", "Region", "Population"],
           ["CAN", 80.66, 1.67, "North America", 33739900],
           ["DEU", 79.84, 1.36, "Europe",        81902307],
           ["DNK", 78.6,  1.84, "Europe",        5523095],
           ["EGY", 72.73, 2.78, "Middle East",   79716203],
           ["GBR", 80.05, 2,    "Europe",        61801570],
           ["IRN", 72.49, 1.7,  "Middle East",   73137148],
           ["IRQ", 68.09, 4.77, "Middle East",   31090763],
           ["ISR", 81.55, 2.96, "Middle East",   7485600],
           ["RUS", 68.6,  1.54, "Europe",        141850000],
           ["USA", 78.09, 2.05, "North America", 307007000]]'>
  </google-chart>
```

Comment: Table seams included in google-chart web component: "pkg: 'table'" in file google-chart-loader.html

Comment: The plunkr works for me in latest Chrome.