# How to use google.visualization.DataTable() in Polymer Google Charts

Tags: javascript, polymer, google-visualization

I am having trouble using the DataTable object of Google Charts in a Polymer application.

I load the Chart elements like this:

```
<link href="/bower_components/google-apis/google-legacy-loader.html" rel="import" />
<link href="/bower_components/google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import" />
```

But when trying to create a DataTable:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In Polymer table(or some chart) is created as:

```
<google-chart
    type="table"
    data='[["ID", "Life Expectancy", "Fertility Rate", "Region", "Population"],
           ["CAN", 80.66, 1.67, "North America", 33739900],
           ["DEU", 79.84, 1.36, "Europe",        81902307],
           ["DNK", 78.6,  1.84, "Europe",        5523095],
           ["EGY", 72.73, 2.78, "Middle East",   79716203],
           ["GBR", 80.05, 2,    "Europe",        61801570],
           ["IRN", 72.49, 1.7,  "Middle East",   73137148],
           ["IRQ", 68.09, 4.77, "Middle East",   31090763],
           ["ISR", 81.55, 2.96, "Middle East",   7485600],
           ["RUS", 68.6,  1.54, "Europe",        141850000],
           ["USA", 78.09, 2.05, "North America", 307007000]]'>
  </google-chart>
```

More examples and docs links here:
[Polymer 1.0 , Google Chart type="table" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45091561/polymer-1-0-google-chart-type-table-not-working)